# Помогите разобраться с python pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Не как не могу разобраться в таких функциях как `pool.join()` и `pool.close()` Читал про них в интернете, но полного понимания это не дало. Можете "по-русски" объяснить зачем они нужны, когда их нужно применять, и какие еще есть функции для работы с `pool`?

Answer (score 1):

ниже представлен пример работы с пулом модуля multiprocessing и функцией map:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import requests


def get(url):
    return requests.get(url).text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = [f'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{i}' for i in range(10)]
    # созадим поток - по личеству ядер
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        # res - это список результатов полученных от всех функций get
        res = pool.map(get, urls)
    print(res)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте текстовых пояснений к коду) ТС, скорее всего, хочет именно их)

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, `import`ы :)

Comment: они почему то не отобразились)

Comment: какой это python? У меня почему-то интерпритатор ругается на неправильный синтаксис в строке `urls = [f'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{i}' for i in range(10)]`

Comment: @nobody, f строки с v3.7

Comment: @nobody если есть возможность - обновитесь до 3.6, так как f-строки быстрый и удобный способ форматирования строк.https://shultais.education/blog/python-f-strings

Comment: @ioprst f-строки в 3.6 появились

Comment: @garrythehotdog, да, ошибся.